# Is it possible to edit 2 nodes at the same time ? In 2 windows

Tags: node-editor, shaders

[image]

In each window one different node to edit, im trying to, but when i switch one the other one switches too...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Found it pick the pin on the far right.